# Definition of eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, self-learning

Eigenvector is such a vector which gets stretched (elongated or compressed by scaling factor of eigenvalue) when linear transformation A is applied to it. Please correct me if wrong

I am trying to understand it geometrically.  given a linear map f or A, for that map, in V vector space, i will search for vectors such that those vectors gets streched / scaled if i map that vector using the given linear transformation. Such vectors in V which gets scaled after f - mapping, those vectors are called eigen vectors. Pls tell whether i am thinking correctly or not.

Comment: @Physor can you pls see my edited comment above

Comment: @Physor "Geometrically, an eigenvector, corresponding to a real nonzero eigenvalue, points in a direction in which it is stretched by the transformation and the eigenvalue is the factor by which it is stretched. If the eigenvalue is negative, the direction is reversed.[2] Loosely speaking, in a multidimensional vector space, the eigenvector is not rotated."

Comment: Geometrically the *nonzero* vectors which retain there direction after being acted upon by the mapping $A$ are called eigenvector. But it in addition to these vectors the kernel of the map $A$ is an egenspace for the eigenvalue zero. recall that the kernel of linear map is the set of the vectors in the domain that are mapped to zero in the codomain

Comment: Eigenvector is mapping $A$ from input space to output space... What do you want to say?

Comment: @Fakemistake can u pls see my edited comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear of what you are asking, but here is an attempt to remove some of your doubts.

**Definition - Eigenvalue and Eigenvector**

> Let $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map of the vector space $V$ into itself. If a proper nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}\in V$ and a scalar $\lambda$ exist such that
> $$f(\mathbf{v})=\lambda \mathbf{v}, $$
> then the proportionality factor $\lambda$ is called an *eigenvalue* for $f$, while $\mathbf{v}$ is called an *eigenvector* belonging to $\lambda$.

Comment: Sir i am trying to understand it geometrically. From the above defination, i can say that given a linear map f or A, for that map, in V vector space, i will search for vectors such that those vectors gets streched / scaled if i map that vector using the given linear transformation. Such vectors in V which gets scaled after f - mapping, those vectors are called eigen vectors. Pls tell whether i am thinking correctly or not. Problem is i am not that good in english.

Comment: You seem to confuse yourself with these "long self explanations". To say it concise, you can just say: "Eigenvectors are vectors that are proportional to their image vectors." @Srinivas

Comment: thank you sir. understood now

Comment: You welcome. If my answer helped you, feel free to upvote it or/and accept it as answer. @Srinivas